# How to create dynamic accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'm trying to make my accordion dynamical in my html template and I don't know how I can do that.

My html template is good, but I don't know how I can add javascript part in order to open/close subpanels with variable `{{category}}` as primary panel.

This is my HTML code :

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                      {{ category }}
                  </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          {% for publication in category.publication.all %}
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordion">
              <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ publication }}
              </div>
           </div>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm pretty new with Javascript and I made something like that, but it doesn't work :

```
function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
}
$('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

I don't know why, but it opens only the first accordion panel, even if I click over the second one or the third one ..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're showing doesn't deal with the hiding/showing of panels, so I'm gonna assume you're using a JS library AND that this library is using ids and datas to map things.

If that's the case, all you need is using unique ids, or else it'll always stop at the first `accordion` it find.

To do it, use your loop indexes :

```
<div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion_{{ category.id }}" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

And link it to your `a` like so :

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_{{ category.id }}" href="#collapseOne_{{ issue }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
```

Here we have an issue : you also need to have one unique id for each `CollapseOne`, but the `publication` loop is after the `a` creation. Anyway, it's weird to have one `a` open multiple elements, so why not make it only one ?

```
<div id="collapseOne_{{ category.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordion">
{% for publication in category.publication.all %}
          <div class="panel-body">
                {{ publication }}
          </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Replace the previous `{{ issue }}` in the `a` with `{{ category }}` and you should be set. Now to find if your library work as assumed ^^

You have to set `{{category.id}}` because if your `category` field contains spaces, it won't work.

Also I'm not used to templates so I hope it let you do that :p

Comment: Thank you with your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I'm sure my issue is about `id/class` names but even if I remove all `id` and replace this by `class`, it doesn't make a link between loop indices and html accordion class to my mind ?

Comment: Well, after pluging my brain in, I figured `toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus')` should just swap the +/- icon. So we don't have the code doing the hidden/shown job. I have rewritten my whole answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried your code, with your modifications but up to now it doesn't work. I don't have hidden/shown accordion part now. I'm letting to continue to search how I can do that ! But thank you ;)

Comment: I found the answer, I have to set ``accordion_{{category.id}}` or `collapseOne_{{ category.id }}` because without id, I got an html id with space ! But with `.id` it works fine !

I edit your answer and make this one as solution.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry to have missed that point and glad you found it. Thanks for the edit.